# How can I make paths in generated NUXT app index.html relative?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

After running

```
yarn generate
```

The generated index.html has absolute paths e.g.

```
/_nuxt/44ae8a8.js
```

What simple setting again can be used to achieve relative paths instead:

```
./_nuxt/44ae8a8.js
```

It's tedious having to do a find and replace and I find the documentation on dir and rootDir properties rather confusing.

Comment: I've already saw this kind of question here. Meanwhile I don't really understand the use issue with it. When you do you need to rewrite this?

Comment: @kissu: I deploy different small demo apps to sub-folders of my webserver