# Relative URL in Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js, scorm2004

I have a problem with Nuxt.js static site generation : I want to have relative url instead of absolute URL because I can't know the final url before the build (i make scorm package who are finaly served by a CDN).

Example : instead of `/_nuxt/1234.js` i want if i'm in /module-1/index.html `../_nuxt/1234.js`.

Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance for your advices !

Comment: Basically this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69657203/8816585

Comment: Yes but the question have no answers... I see other person with the same issue but no one give a solution for now...

Comment: Maybe this article can help, https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-i-generated-dynamic-routes-for-different-nuxt-js-pages-ce2ee6972743

Comment: Thanks but it not solved the problem : I don't need to generate dynamic routes, i want to have relative path. I've now the impression that it is not possible...